# Post-hoc test after using general linear model (GLM)

Tags: r, glm, poisson, posthoc

I want to see if there's a significant difference between 3 groups (klasse) and their agressive behaviour (by counting the number of agressive interactions). The situation is not relevant, but it must be taken into account. I compared the agressive interactions between the groups with a general linear model and I used the family poisson for the count data.

This is the data input in Rstudio:

```
data.frame(agressiekrab=c(8,5,1,10,6,12,4,17,1,1,5,9,11,2,3,0,21,17,4,1,10,4,14,15,22,8,19,0,6,16,4,10), klasse=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), situatie=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))

structure(list(agressiekrab = c(8, 5, 1, 10, 6, 12, 4, 17, 1, 
1, 5, 9, 11, 2, 3, 0, 21, 17, 4, 1, 10, 4, 14, 15, 22, 8, 19, 
0, 6, 16, 4, 10), klasse = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
), situatie = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

It's non-parametric data, so not normally distributed
This is the code that I used in Rstudio:

```
agmodel1<-glm(agressiekrab~klasse*situatie,poisson) 
summary(agmodel1)
```

The result is this:

```
Call:
glm(formula = agressiekrab ~ klasse * situatie, family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-3.688  -1.623  -0.462   1.306   3.718  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       1.5198     0.3812   3.987 6.68e-05 ***
klasse            0.7223     0.1827   3.953 7.71e-05 ***
situatie          0.0905     0.2112   0.428  0.66836    
klasse:situatie  -0.3251     0.1169  -2.781  0.00542 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 171.19  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 120.51  on 28  degrees of freedom
AIC: 240.09

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Now i would like to use a post-hoc test to see where the difference is between de groups (klasse). I tried the pairwise wilcox test, but it doesn't give me two-by-two comparisons. I don't know how to interpret the outcome.
I also tried the TukeyHSD test, but that didn't work either (and I don't think it's right because of the non-parametric data)

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(agressiekrab,klasse*situatie,P.adj="Bonj")
   Pairwise comparisons using Wilcoxon rank sum test 
   data:  agressiekrab and klasse * situatie £
      1 2 3 4
    2 1 - - -  
    3 1 1 - -
    4 1 1 1 -
    6 1 1 1 1 
  P value adjustment method: holm
```

The tukey method gives an error:

```
TukeyHSD(aov(agressiekrab~klasse*situatie))    
  Error in TukeyHSD.aov(aov(agressiekrab ~ klasse * situatie)) : 
  no factors in the fitted model
```

Comment: can you provide your example in R code, so people can reproduce everything more easily? If you got errors with TukeyHSD what was the error, and how did you use the function? Generally it is easier if you let us have a look at exactly what you were doing

Comment: Okay, I added all the code en the outcome that I generated

Comment: nice, thank you. If you would also provide the data.frame, it would go even easier. You appended a picture, but something like `data.frame(agressiekrab=c(8,5,1), klasse=c(1,1,1), situatie=c(1,1,1))` would be easier. You can use the `dput` function on your data.frame to get an output you can paste in your poste.

Comment: Data.frame is now in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
TukeyHSD(aov(agressiekrab~factor(klasse)*factor(situatie)))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply